# ¿Cómo es la expresión regular en SQL server para encontrar dos o más palabras?

Tags: sql, sql-server, r

Por ejemplo, en R para poder encontrar las palabras `azul` o `rojo` en una columna se usa la función `grepl()` y expresión regular `|`, así:

```
grepl("azul|rojo",var1)
```

En SQL server, entiendo que se podría hacer con la función `LIKE`. Intenté de la siguiente manera:

```
select * from tab1
where var1 like '%azul%|%rojo%'
```

Pero no obtengo el resultado esperado.

¿Cómo sería la sintaxis?

Comment: No hay expresiones regulares nativas en SQL Server, pero puedes implementar algún CLR en .NET para agregar esta funcionalidad, por lo demás, la respuesta de Luis es la indicada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No existe una expresión que pueda funcionar como tal en SQL Server ya que las expresiones regulares están muy limitadas a unos cuantos comodines.

Tendrías que usar dos condicionales unidas por `OR`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   tab1
WHERE  var1 LIKE '%azul%'
OR     var1 LIKE '%rojo%';
```

Si existen otras condiciones, es mejor usar paréntesis para agruparlas.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   tab1
WHERE  col1 <> 0
AND   (var1 LIKE '%azul%' OR var1 LIKE '%rojo%')
AND    fecha < GETDATE();
```

Answer (score -1):

espero entender bien, ¿qué te parece hacer esto?:

```
select * from tab1 where var1 IN ('azul','rojo')
```

los valores tienen que ser exactos.

Comment: Entiendo, que sería la sintaxis para encontrar la palabra exacta, pero mi duda era para los casos en donde contenga `azul` o `rojo`.